# Rails - Testing "edit" action from a resource in Cucumber+Capybara with session involved

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I have declared this in the routes:

```
resources :lessons
```

And I am trying to create a test for edit a lesson by using the following feature:

```
Feature: Edit Lesson
  As a logged in user of the website
  I want to edit a lesson
  so I can change the values on it

    Scenario: I am signed in and I edit an existing lesson
      Given I am logged in
      And I access the edit lesson page
      When I edit an existing lesson with correct values
      Then I should see a lesson edited message
```

And then I have the following steps:

```
def valid_user
  @user ||= { :name => "Testy McUserton", :email => "testy@userton.com",
    :password => "please", :password_confirmation => "please", :description => "I love to play soccer"}
end

Given /^I am logged in$/ do
  sign_up valid_user
end
```

**Here is where I have the doubt:**

```
And /^I access the edit lesson page$/ do
  visit edit_lesson_path(???)
end
```

The edit lesson path is expecting an id, so I suppose I should "create" a lesson, but in order to create that lesson, the user_id of the current user in session is needed.  How am I supposed to do this in Cucumber+Capybara? I am using **Devise** to manage authentication, user sessions and so.

Here is how I create a new lesson, and why I need the user_id in somehow:

```
def create
    @lesson = Lesson.new(params[:lesson])
    @lesson.user_id = current_user.id
    if @lesson.save
      redirect_to lesson_path(@lesson)
      flash[:notice] = "Congrats! Lesson has been created successfully."
    else
      render :action => "new"
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the test cases with capybara cucumber , You have to manage `background:` process which can work for whole feature

After that you have to get the data on which you want it to be edited

Sample code can be like this

```
Backgound:
 Given the following users:
  | email          | company_name   | role  | confirmed | pending |
  | admin@test.com | xyz            | admin | true      | false   |
@javascript
Scenario: Specifying company
 Given "xyz" has the following lesson:
  | name    |
  | lesson1 |
 And I access the edit lesson page
 When I edit an "lesson1" with correct values
 Then I should see a "lesson1" edited message
```

This is will help you to get your lesson with background process been mention for the whole Feature as background runs every time Scenario is been called from the same feature.